# Demystifying postgresql \ internal queries

Tags: php, psql

I'm a fairly new to postgresql and need to build a custom backup and restore script in php.  From reading posts on here, I learnt of `psql -E` which will output to the terminal the sql for a \ command postgres uses to describe a sequence, table, view, etc.
What I can not figure out so that I can replicate the sql statements in my work is how 2 or more sql statements are combined to achieve the end result.  For example, `\d mytable` will output the structure for a table that I can use to make a CREATE TABLE script for a backup script.  That takes 4 queries though.  Is there a set method to taking those queries and combining them?

Comment: Are you asking how to execute `psql -E` from PHP, how to parse `psql`'s output, how to generate `CREATE TABLE` statements or none of the above?

Comment: I am asking how to take any set of queries `psql -E` displays in a slash command (`\d mytable` as an example) so I can make sense of it to use in php code.  There has to be some kind of logic for how 2 or more queries are used or chained together.  They are not sub-queries.  Are they functions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `psql`'s informational queries (`\ commands`) for this. What you need is `pg_dump`, not `psql`. `psql` shows you a human-readable view of how a table looks; `pg_dump` gives you the DDL to re-create it, which is what you say you want since you're attempting to create a "backup script".

Unfortunately at present `pg_dump` is not really callable as a library, and it isn't simple to extract its queries. Instead you'll generally need to invoke `pg_dump` as a shell command.

For views, you can use the SQL function `SELECT pg_get_viewdef('view_name')`. Unfortunately there is no equivalent for tables, or many other database objects. See [system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html).

Like `psql`, `pg_dump` may use a series of queries to construct the SQL text for a given command. You can find how `pg_dump` constructs these in the [source code for `pg_dump`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/bin/pg_dump), particularly the monstrous [`pg_dump.c`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c). See [`dumpTable()` for instance](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_dump.c#L12842).

Beware, if you try to copy how `pg_dump` does it, you'll create a maintenance nightmare for yourself. Remember, the PostgreSQL catalogs are not guranteed to be stable from version to version - tools like `psql` and `pg_dump`, and the `information_schema`, generally protect you from such changes. If you go delving in the catalogs, you're going to have to re-test every time there's a major version release, and deal with any backward compat breaks. Take a look at all the version-specific cases in `pg_dump` to get an idea of what you're getting yourself into.

I think this sucks, and that the core functionality of `pg_dump` should be in a `libpqdump` or in a server-side extension, but unfortunately it isn't, and nobody is willing to do the large amount of work required to make that possible.

Short version: Just use `pg_dump`. It supports selective dump options like `-t` if you need them.

Comment: +1 I'm pretty sure this is what the OP wants, even though he denies so. This is a classical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) IMHO.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Huh, I didn't know that fallacy had a name. I usually write (when I can be bothered) sometihng like "Please explain the *why* to this *how*; what the underlying problem is that you're trying to solve, not how you think you should be solving it."

Comment: @CraigRinger. If using pg_dump was an option, I would not be attempting to write my own and restore back-up script to manipulate the database via a browser.  The ISP I am using for production/hosting has a very limiting interface of only PhpPgAdmin. Using pg_dump is okay on my development side, but having reviewed the switches and options to scale it down, it still generates a dump file that requires heavy editing before I can copy and paste easily into a PhpPgAdmin query textarea. I have discovered a method to query elements to rebuild with `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @dwlamb That's the kind of thing you mention in the question. Though in this case there isn't really any alternative. You can write code to dump the DB, but I guarantee you'll get it wrong or miss things - inheritance, partial expression indexes, constraints, etc etc. If you can constrain the subset of features used to what your code knows how to dump then that might be viable, but then ... if you can do that, why not just record the DDL you ran in the first place? To me, the answer here is "get a better ISP".